# Accessing the video feed of a cheap FPV drone

Tags: quadcopters, first-person-view, software

A while ago, I bought a small and cheap WIFI FPV drone to fly in the office and at home (not outside). It's very funny (It's my first drone ever) and now I would like to access the video stream directly and build my own client because the mobile app is sh*t.

That's the app I need to use to get the video from the drone: [Butterfly Ufo Drone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guanzhi.tech.butterfly_fpv&hl=en&gl=US). 
 And that's the link to the drone I bought: [KF608 mini HD RC Drone Quadcopter](https://www.dx.com/p/kf608-mini-hd-rc-drone-quadcopter-wifi-remote-control-airplane-toy-2711064.html#.X6qvU2hKguU).

To be able to use the app, I need to be in the WIFI network of the drone, so I think I could somehow find out the IP and the target port on which the video will be streamed.

Has anyone ever done something like this? Or does someone know directly a solution?

I'm a software developer so the programming stuff is not a problem. I'm struggling with finding the correct endpoint and stream to catch the video.

Edit: I found a repository on GitHub to hijack some drones. Unfortunately not for mine but for many others. So if someone comes around this question with the same problem try the code from that repository: [RCL-RC127](https://github.com/boltgolt/rcl-rc127)

Comment: I think you might be more likely to get an answer from a hacking forum, this sort of thing is pretty rare in the hobby flying world.  That said, it's a fascinating question and I'd love to hear the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little familiar with this - the task is hard and the suggestion to talk to the hacking side is very wise, to wit - here is a primer from my messing around. (also a software developer w/over 20 years experience).

To find out the IP, that is very easy - look to your router and check on leases or devices.  Unless you have static IP assignments or similar, the IP will change overtime but generally stay the same on a calm network.

For capturing the stream - Wireshark is in your future (https://www.wireshark.org/) and you will need to know the protocol being used and  various transport mechanisms then reconstruct that data for your end use.  It is safe to assume that the guys in Shenzhen took the fast, easy, hacky, free/open source route.  Chips in used will also provide clues.

I have worked a bit in wifi security hiring people to corrupt wifi data for tech presentations - your task is not one I would ever take on (out of my wheelhouse).  Still I have tried this exact hack a few times and have been defeated universally.

I got around this by using a USB HDMI capture box and porting in the analog signal.  $200 part and 1h set up and I can stream from goggle to internet. The capture box is something I am glad I have and the 10days of work I skipped hacking signals is not forgotten.